# php session dropped after form submit

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session

Seems, that I can't add password protection to the script: it should allow to login with the pass and to submit data from the form to mysql. Login looks fine, but if I try to press submit, it returns me to login page. Seems, that session is dropped or overwritten, but is not clear, how:

```
//login area
<?php 
$password = "test"; 
session_start();
$_SESSION['txtPassword']= $_POST['txtPassword'] ;
if ( $_SESSION['txtPassword']!=$password ) {
?>
<form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> 
<p><label for="txtPassword">Password:</label> 
<br /><input type="text" title="Enter your password" name="txtPassword" /></p> 
<p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" /></p> 
</form> 
<?  
}
elseif (  $_SESSION['txtPassword']=$password ) { 
echo $_SESSION['txtPassword'] ; // tried to print password, result is correct:      test 

//my db connection, just in case:
include "config.php";
$connect = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, NAME);

// data which should be inserted to db
if 
(@$_POST['posted']=='1' $_POST['posted'])) {
 $sSQL = "UPDATE users SET user_login='".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['usern'])."',user_pass='".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, dohashpw($_POST['passw']))."' WHERE ID=1";
mysqli_query($connect, $sSQL) or print(mysql_error());
print ' <div class="container"> <p class="pstype">Password updated! </p>';
...
 //input form 
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"><input   type="hidden" name="posted" value="1" />

 <div class="col-xs-3">
 <label for="ex2">New Username: </label> 
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="usern" >
 </div>

 <div class="col-xs-3">
 <label for="ex2">New Password: </label> 
 <input type="password"  class="form-control input-lg" name="passw" >
 </div>

 <div class="col-xs-3">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="<? mysqli_query ($connect, $sSQL);?>; ">
 </div>
 </form>
```

I am able to login this page, but when I fill the form and click Submit, I get login area again. If echo $_SESSION show a correct result, I think that it was established, but data are lost after for submit. Could you please help to find my error?

Comment: Sidenote: For one thing, passing passwords in sessions isn't a very good idea. Either way, check for errors.

Comment: This isn't comparing, `elseif (  $_SESSION['txtPassword']=$password )`. What is `@$_POST['posted']=='1' $_POST['posted']` suppose to do?

Comment: Sidenote 2 : You should Hash and Salt your passwords.

Comment: `mysql_error` won't work with `mysqli`, `onclick="<? mysqli_query` wont work. PHP is server side. `onClick` can only occur client side. Also do you have short tags enabled? Look into AJAX.

Comment: use echo and check whether $_POST['txtPassword'] ; return the password correctly

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning and not comparing here :

```
elseif (  $_SESSION['txtPassword']=$password ) {
```

this is better

```
elseif (  $_SESSION['txtPassword']==$password ) {
```

but thats a bad idea anyway, passwords should not be stored in session variables like this, and you have to hash them once the user submit them and only manipulate and store the hashed passwords in your code and database

Comment: Yes you are right. But it is not the problem here. because if condition executed here.That is the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$password = "test"; 
session_start();
$_SESSION['txtPassword']= $_POST['txtPassword'] ;
if($_SESSION['txtPassword']!=$password ){
?>
   <form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ? >"> 
   <p><label for="txtPassword">Password:</label></p>
   </br>
   <p><input type="text" title="Enter your password" name="txtPassword"/> </p> 
   <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"/></p> 
   </form> 

<?php  
}
else{ 
 echo $_SESSION['txtPassword'];
}
?>
```

i am not understanding why the elseif stands for? you are already checking inside the if condition which both are not equal?.